# unable to set result from ajax success to div html in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the below code, I'm calling an action and getting a partialviewresult in ajax success.

But I'm unable to set the html to the div-Graph, but I'm getting undefined in alert; alert( $('#div-Graph').html()); The entire html is disappearing...

Any idea on this?

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ChartTypes').change(function () {

```
        var selectedID = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/charts/GetChart/4',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {
                debugger    ;
                $('#div-Graph').html(result.toString());
                alert( $('#div-Graph').html());
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Kindly let me know if you need any more code parts. Tried a lot for a solution :(

Thanks
Ragesh

Comment: are you expecting result to be in JSON format? if so, you might want to consider JSON.stringify(result) instead of result.toString()

Comment: in ajax you can't pass parameter like this `url: '/charts/GetChart/4',`. You can specify parameters in `data` as follow  `$.ajax({ url: '/charts/GetChart', data:{paramName: paramValue},type: 'GET',success: function (result)`

Comment: Why are even converting it a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly append it to the class/id like this.  You can't display the whole div inside the alert box.

```
  success: function (result) {
       alert(result);
       var res = JSON.stringify(result);
      $('#div-Graph').append(res);    
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! But it is still undefined, While debugging; after executing  $('#div-Graph').append(result.toString()); the entire html is going off.. :(

Comment: Try now. I have updated my answer. First before that check whether you are actually getting output using `console.log(result);` or `alert("result");` do this before doing anything else.

Comment: Thank you :) the result is appended now, but not as expected. You answered the question. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help :)